# Getting first name, last name and email from Keycloak using Quarkus OIDC integration

Tags: keycloak, quarkus-oidc

When I access the /openid-connect/token endpoint using admin_cli client_id I can see more/different info in the payload of returned access_token compared to when token is injected into my bean by the Quarkus OIDC/Keycloak extension.

Here are some samples:

```
{
  "exp": 1671084133,
  "iat": 1671083533,
  "jti": "b95bac0a-f95e-413d-b2cd-3b97fcf5f3c8",
  "iss": "http://localhost:51521/realms/my-realm",
  "sub": "cda64011-47a8-4a6a-8aac-06c7db6fc593",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "be12a28b-4143-4bbf-9914-c8454d93f50f",
  "acr": "1",
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "be12a28b-4143-4bbf-9914-c8454d93f50f",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "test",
  "given_name": "vasia",
  "family_name": "pupkin",
  "email": "test@test.com"
}
```

Versus

```
{
  "exp": 1671086253,
  "iat": 1671085653,
  "auth_time": 1671085653,
  "jti": "05e9f66d-54a1-440b-9295-3ebd681a853a",
  "iss": "http://localhost:51521/realms/my-realm",
  "sub": "cda64011-47a8-4a6a-8aac-06c7db6fc593",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "my-app",
  "session_state": "ba00821c-1556-4214-90d7-5f2a55b0074a",
  "scope": "openid microprofile-jwt",
  "sid": "ba00821c-1556-4214-90d7-5f2a55b0074a",
  "upn": "test",
  "groups": [
    "offline_access",
    "admin",
    "uma_authorization",
    "default-roles-collar-club"
  ]
}
```

I'm interested in still getting the groups (for role based access) and given_name, family_name, email properties as well in my Quarkus app.
Tried to specify: *quarkus.oidc.authentication.scopes=openid,profile,groups* - getting error in the url redirected from Keycloak:

```
2022-12-14 23:11:19,984 DEBUG [io.qua.oid.run.CodeAuthenticationMechanism] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) Authentication has failed, error: invalid_scope, description: Invalid scopes: openid openid profile groups
```

Answer (score 0):

`openid` is always added by Quarkus, Keycloak does not like duplicate scope values, so remove `openid`

Comment: After openid removed fails  with: 2023-02-02 00:52:14,896 DEBUG [io.qua.oid.run.CodeAuthenticationMechanism] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Authentication has failed, error: invalid_scope, description: Invalid scopes: openid profile groups

Comment: I still need your help with this, please.

Comment: Hi, I think it is a Keycloak setup issue. As far as Quarkus is concerned it passes the requested scopes to KC. Probably 'groups' is not supported,  AFAIK it is enabled indirectly via an mpjwt option in KC. So my guess you need to have openid and profile scopes only, if it does not work then please open a Keycloak Github Discussion and CC me as @sberyozkin, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... For anybody looking to achieve the same - make sure you have the right scope(s) added to the client in Keycloak (Clients -> Client Scopes -> Add client Scope).
[screenshot with email scope added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv2I5.png)